# Как узнать загрузились ли данные посредством get()

Tags: jquery

Как при выполняемом GET-запросе отобразить анимированную картинку `/images/ajax-loader.gif`, а в случае получения данных убрать ее и показать данные.
(такое есть в jquerymobile, картинка выводится в центре экрана)

```
// Пример запроса
    $.get("index", "getdata", serverResponse, "json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
// блок содержащий картинку, по умолчанию display: none
var $preloader = $('.preloader');

// функция для показа картинки, класс active отвечает за видимость
// в CSS: .active {display:block}
function togglePreloader (state) {
    $preloader.toggleClass('active', state);
}

// функция-обертка над $.get запросом
function getData () {
    togglePreloader(true); // показываем прелоадер
    $.get('url', 'data', dataReady); // запрос на сервер
}

// сервер вернул данные
function dataReady (data) {
    togglePreloader(false); // скрываем прелоадер
    // продолжаем работу
}
```

Comment: Добавил два класса со свойствами `none` и `block`, принцип работы тоже понял. К сожалению, картинка не отображается. Если убрать класс `preloader` изображение присутствует. Пришел к выводу что класс `active` почему-то не ставится. Изображение располагал до и после `jquery-кода`. На что обратить внимание?

Comment: Не нужно 2 класса. Нужен один active

Comment: Если я правильно понял работу, то будет так: `<div align="center" style="display: none;" class="preloader"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>`   ====>    `<div align="center" style="display: none;" class="preloader active"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>` но второй код не показывает картинку. Может можно изменять свойство `display` с `none` на `block` (возможно, я неправильно понял работу с html)

Comment: style='display: none' уберите. Это должно быть в стилях preloader, а не тут. Style перекрывает всё что есть в классах.

Comment: Скажите, можно ли как-то поместить `togglePreloader(true);` внутрь `$.get('url', 'data', dataReady);` примерно так же как вы поместили его внутрь `function getData () {` ?

Comment: Конечно нет. На то и нужна обертка над $.get